# Can't open file streams for writing on iPhone with XCode in C++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm working on a game written in C++ and trying to get it to work on iOS via XCode. Most things seem to be working at this point, however, I can't write to files.

This is the code that loads the user's save data (it's just an int denoting how far into the game they've made it). I can load this data just fine with no problems.

```
    void ManagerState::LoadProgress()
    {
        std::ifstream saveFile;
        saveFile.open(mSavePath, std::ifstream::in);
        if(!saveFile)
        {
            Opal::Logger::LogString("Failed to open save file!");
        }
        else
        {
            saveFile >> mCurrentConversation;
            saveFile.close();
        }
    }
```

However, this code, which is almost identical, does not work. I get this message printed to the console when I check errno after trying to open the file "Error Operation not permitted". It seems like I don't have write permission for the files that I copied to the device.

```
    void ManagerState::SaveProgress()
    {
        std::ofstream saveFile;
        saveFile.open(mSavePath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

        char buffer[ 256 ];
        strerror_r( errno, buffer, 256 ); // get string message from errno, XSI-compliant version
        printf("Error %s", buffer);
        
        if(!saveFile)
        {
            Opal::Logger::LogString("Failed to open save file!");
        }
        else
        {
            saveFile << mCurrentConversation - 1;
            saveFile.close();
        }
    }
```

[This is the setup for copying resources to the device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyLI2.png)

I've tried

- Using SDL's file I/O
- Using C-style file I/O (fopen)
- not truncating the file

Nothing has worked.

Can anyone tell me how to either enable write permissions on the files I copied, or how to get them on the device in a way that allows me to save and read data from them?

Comment: What's the value of `mSavePath`? An app Resource file/directory is read only. All resources compiled as part of your app cannot be modified. To store save files, create a directory in the Documents directory or (Application Support directory)[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/applicationsupportdirectory]

Comment: mSavePath goes here "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5C4B80A0-616A-4238-AEFD-B835B7F42377/OfMoonsAndMania.app/SaveGame/SaveGame.txt".   The link you posted doesn't work.

Comment: @Ludius: Indeed, the path `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/*/*.app` is **read-only**. As @mani wrote, instead store inside `Documents`, `Private Documents`, `Cache` or temporary directory, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Files bundled with the app are read-only.

You need to store your save file in Documents or App support directory or similar to which you have read/write access during runtime.

More here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/applicationsupportdirectory

So one way to accomplish this is using an objective c++ class to get the app support directory where you can store the `save` file. If you make your c++ class objective c++ you can directly call `Utilties` class methods from within your c++.

Header: `Utilities.h`

```
@interface Utilities: NSObject

+ (void)setupFromAppBundleOnce;
+ (NSString*)getSavedFilePath;

@end
```

Implementation: `Utilities.mm` (Note `.mm` file extension is objective c++)

```
@implementation Utilities

+ (void)setupFromAppBundleOnce {
  NSString* localSavePath = [Utilities localSaveFilePath];
  // if local save file doesn't exist, load the save file supplied in the app bundle
  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: ]) {
    NSURL* appBundleSaveFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SaveGame" ofType:@"txt"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:appBundleSaveFile.path toPath:localSavePath error:NULL];
  }
}

+ (NSString*)localSaveFilePath {
  NSURL* supportFileDir = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                                        inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
  return [supportFileDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SaveGame.txt"].path;
}

@end
```

When your app loads, call `[Utilties setupFromAppBundleOnce]` in objective c or c++. Or call `Utilities.setupFromAppBundleOnce()` in swift.

Then call `[[Utitilies getSavedFilePath] UTF8String]` which you can pass to your cpp `mSavePath`.